# Phoenix Hbase: ResultSet.next() runs into StackOverflowError

Tags: hbase, resultset, apache-phoenix

I am seeing a weird error while iterating over the `ResultSet` of a query.
My code is in Java and I do something like the following:

```
  String sql = " SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATE_TIME > 'something' ORDER BY DATE_TIME DESC LIMIT 1"
  ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.execute(sql);

  while(rs.next()){
     //Code never enters this block
  }
```

While debugging I found that when the execution reaches rs.next(), it runs into some kind of error and throws up StackOverFlowError. 
I am trying to debug more but if anyone knows or understands why this happens, please help. 
Thanks in advance.

```
 org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: THREAT_VIEW,,1431123584956.a0075602ce1d3ed11929c84e62686e45.: null
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.throwIOException(ServerUtil.java:52)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.BaseScannerRegionObserver$2.nextRaw(BaseScannerRegionObserver.java:309)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.DelegateRegionScanner.nextRaw(DelegateRegionScanner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2035)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes$LexicographicalComparerHolder$UnsafeComparer.compareTo(Bytes.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.compareTo(Bytes.java:1223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparator.compareRows(CellComparator.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparator.compare(CellComparator.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue$KVComparator.compare(KeyValue.java:1968)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue$KVComparator.compare(KeyValue.java:1897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.binarySearch(Bytes.java:1901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlockIndex$BlockIndexReader.rootBlockContainingKey(HFileBlockIndex.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlockIndex$BlockIndexReader.loadDataBlockWithScanInfo(HFileBlockIndex.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$AbstractScannerV2.seekTo(HFileReaderV2.java:625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$AbstractScannerV2.seekTo(HFileReaderV2.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekAtOrAfter(StoreFileScanner.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekToPreviousRow(StoreFileScanner.java:449)
```

Comment: hi reoger do you find the solution of this error because i also same kind of error

Comment: @TanmayAgrawal posted a solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems the version of Hbase used doesnt support REVERSE Ordering ON pk.

so `ORDER BY START_TIME` -> would work. 
But `ORDER BY START_TIME DESC` --> would not work